# Do not understand code to space between consecutive digits

Tags: c++

While i work on a problem stating that given any positive integer, I need to design a programme so that it creates a space between 2 consecutive digits. No avail for 2 hours, I decide to google online to get some hints. I obtained the following code and it works perfectly. However, I do not understand how the code works, especially the if. I do not see how the conditions are met if input is `12345`.

```
int main()
{
    char b; //stores the digit
    cin >> b; //get single character from user input
    while (b != '\0') //while not at null terminator from user pressing enter
    {
        if (b >= '0' && b <= '9') //if entered character is a digit
        {
            cout << b << " "; //print character with a space
        }
         cin >> b; //get next character to check if it is null terminator or another digit
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? You could also run the code in your debugger and step through line by line, to grasp what's going on. `if` isn't a loop BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not understand the condition in if(b >= '0' && b <= '9'). For example, if b = 12345, why would the condition be satisfied?

Comment: The condition is satisfied because `char` values are represented as numbers, for digits these are guaranteed to be consecutive. You should lookup ASCII values for example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is it guaranteed that the machine uses ASCII? How is the consecutiveness guaranteed?

Comment: @Ayxan I never said this. It's guaranteed that digits are reprsented as consecutive number values though. You might have a look at an EBCDIC table for example.

Comment: @Ayxan The numeric values of the representation of any charset are always in ascending order from `'0'` to `'9'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user types anything, the program stores it in a buffer (think of the buffer as a string that the computer as access to).

When the program reaches `cin >> b;`, it checks the buffer. As the user hasn't typed anything yet, the buffer is empty. So the programs waits for the user to type something.
The user types `12345[enter]`. This is put in the buffer, and the cin use the buffer to fullfill `cin >> b;`.

What does this do ? `b` is a char, a single ASCII character. So `b` needs a single character, and `cin` provides the first one in the buffer, here it's `1`.
(stays `2345[enter]` in the buffer).

Then the program evalutates the condition
`(b >= '0' && b <= '9')`. It's important here to see that `'1'` and `'9'` are not `int`, they are characters too! So the program compares the numerical values of those characters, and it happens that all numerical character are placed in order, with nothing else inbetween. So the condition is true if `b` holds a numerical character, and so we can print `b` with a following space.
The program will then ask for the next character in the buffer, which is `'2'` in our example. So `b` will only check characters one by one, and not all the entry at once!

How does the programs stop ? As explained in the comments, the while loop ends when `b= '\0'`. `'\0'` is a special character, a null terminator, used the end of a string. So this program ends when the while loop reaches the end of the user's input.

Comment: _"`'\0'` is a special character, a null terminator, used the end of a string. So this program ends when the while loop reaches the end of the user's input."_ Not precisely in this case. There's no `NUL` terminated string in the buffer. A special EOF value would be sent to the program if CTRL-D or CTRL-Z (depends on OS) is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

when you enter integer>9 in a character compiler stores it as a string.

if in your code you remove second cin program enters infinite loop and keeps on printing first integer.

second cin takes next numeric value from b and print it. when last integer is printed buffer gets empty and waits for user to enter the number

Comment: I think the OP is more asking about how `if (b >= '0' && b <= '9')` specifically works. You should explain that in your answer.